# pudb3 - skip lines to next breakpoint in pudb

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, pudb

Say I'm in a code block and pressing `n` would mean the program ends, as the next line exits the program - how  do I skip lines to the next breakpoint a few lines down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `s` - 'step into' - pressing this jumps to the current cursor line.